# Dynamically change content in SharePoint 2013 Search Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint-2013

I have one function with one param and I have to get the data dynamically from NavDropdownListContainer and set it in the Search TextBox using JQuery or JavaScript.

Please find below the screenshot and css related to it.

[SharePoint 2013 SearchBox](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=4db2f6f)

Help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="ms-floatLeft" id="SearchBox" name="Control">
    <div class="ms-srch-sbLarge ms-srch-sb-borderFocused" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_sboxdiv">
        <input title="Search Everything" class="ms-textLarge ms-srch-sbLarge-navWidth ms-srch-sb-prompt ms-helperText" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_sbox" accesskey="S" onkeydown="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.activateDefaultQuerySuggestionBehavior();" onkeypress="if (Srch.U.isEnterKey(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) { $getClientControl(this).search(this.value);return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event); }" onfocus="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.hidePrompt();ctl.setBorder(true);" onblur="var ctl = $getClientControl(this);ctl.showPrompt();ctl.setBorder(false);" type="text" maxlength="2048" value="" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
        <a title="Navigation" class="ms-srch-sb-navLink ms-srch-sb-navLink-menuOpen" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavButton" onclick="$getClientControl(this).activateDefaultNavigationBehavior();return Srch.U.cancelEvent(event);" href="javascript: {}"> <img class="ms-srch-sbLarge-navImg" id="navImg" alt="Navigation" src="/_layouts/15/images/searchresultui.png?rev=23"> </a>
        <a title="Search" class="ms-srch-sb-searchLink" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_SearchLink" onclick="$getClientControl(this).search($get('ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_sbox').value);" href="javascript: {}"> <img class="ms-srch-sbLarge-searchImg" id="searchImg" alt="Search" src="/_layouts/15/images/searchresultui.png?rev=23"> </a>
        <div class="ms-qSuggest-container ms-shadow" id="AutoCompContainer">
            <div id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_AutoCompList"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ms-qSuggest-container ms-shadow" id="NavDropdownListContainer" style="display: block; visibility: visible; position: absolute;">
            <div class="ms-qSuggest-list" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList" style="width: 498px;">
                <div class="ms-qSuggest-hListItem">Everything</div>
                <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Videos</div>
                <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">People</div>
                <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Conversations</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified code as follows in the "Control_Searchbox.html" which is located under Sites Settings > Web Designer Galleries > Master pages and page layouts > Display Templates > Search:

```
    //alert('Ready');
    var searchScope = GetUrlKeyValue("searchscope", false, location.href);
    //alert(searchScope);

    if(searchScope != ""){
        var navNodes = ctx.ClientControl.get_navigationNodes();
        //alert(navNodes);
        if (navNodes.length > 0) {
              var nodeName;
              var nodePromptString;
              var nodeUrl;

                for (var i = 0; i < navNodes.length; ++i) {
                    nodeName = navNodes[i].name;
                    nodePromptString = navNodes[i].promptString;
                    nodeUrl = navNodes[i].url;

                    //alert(nodeName + '/' + nodePromptString + '/' + nodeUrl + ' - ' + searchScope);

                    if(nodeName.toUpperCase() == searchScope.toUpperCase()){
                        ctx.ClientControl.set_resultsPageAddress(nodeUrl);             
                        prompt = nodePromptString;
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Hence whenever you wanna access one of the results sources, you have to pass the querystring as

```
http://siteurl/Search/Seiten/default.aspx?searchscope=Everything
```

Complete [Control_SearchBox.html](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:516c)